# "File System is Read-Only" error happens repeatedly in Ubuntu-Budgie 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, filesystem, ssd, budgie

I have a dual booted laptop consisting of Windows 10 and Ubuntu Budgie 18.04. Both of them have been installed on a 256GB SSD. In Ubuntu Budgie, after using for a long while like around 4-5 hrs suddenly I start getting the "File system is Read-Only error", I google about this issue and found that I had to run `fsck -yf <disk>`, when I run this its fixes the issue, but it continues to happen again and again. Earlier I had dual booted on a HDD, this was my first time using an SSD. Is there any permanent solution to fix this issue? I get very annoyed when this error occurs out of nowhere when I am working on something.
For my system, the Read-Only error happens on /dev/sdb5, so I run `fsck -yf /dev/sdb5` and it gets fixed but after certain time it happens again. I would be really glad to get a permanent solution to fix this.

Comment: A *file-system* flips to RO because inconsistencies are detected, and flipping RO prevents data-loss.  The requirement to run a `fsck` only fixes the symptom of the problem, without touching the cause. Did you explore logs as to why the file-system tripped RO?  (`dmesg` will show issues only for current system, lost at reboot, but `journalctl` should still contain clues) I'd look there (and likely evaluate the health of the drive, ie. using its SMART (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools))

Comment: I tried running S.M.A.R.T but the status shows `interrupted (host reset)`. I tried both short and long tests. Here are the screenshots of gsmartcontrol for the SSD - [Screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/ATDzo8A). I couldn't make mush sense of the things.

Comment: I ran `dmesg -H` and this was the output - (https://imgur.com/a/sUeXzHf)